# TPM 2.0 Reissued EK Cert

Tags: public-key, certificates, trusted-platform-module

Unlike the `TPM 1.2` module, the `TPM 2.0` specification allows the platform user to create own `EK` (Endorsement Key) using `EPS` (Endorsement Primary Seed) and `EKTemplate` and obtain a certificate signed by the Privacy CA corresponding to the public key.

According to `TPM 2.0` specification

1. the manufacturer can install the already generated certificate for the common template provided by the specification.
2. the manufacturer must have already generated certificates for all templates with zero unique field.

My questions (can't find answers in specification);

1. According to which protocol can a TPM administrator obtain certificates for an `EK` public key that is generated not by a standard template, but by a template that contains a random set of bytes in a unique field (also `EKNonce`)?
2. Does the manufacturer keep secret `EPS`? And if not, then he will understand that the key `EK` generated with this template (the trust to the platform administrator)?